# Different restrictions on media library modal

Tags: wordpress, filter, advanced-custom-fields

I know it's possible to restrict the media library modal's items using the [ajax_query_attachments_args](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/ajax_query_attachments_args) filter, but is it possible to do so differently wether you're editing a field or another of a same post ?

For example : i have an ACF Gallery field on a post type, and i want its images to only be a selection of images, while the other media libraries on the page (featured image, editor add media, ...) still displays all the images.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACF Support provided me [an answer](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/filter-gallery-items/), so i'm sharing it here :

Using the *ajax_query_attachments_args* filter, it is possible to identify the field initiating the request, as "_acfuploader" :

```
Array
    (
        [action] => query-attachments
        [post_id] => 838
        [query] => Array
        (
            [post_mime_type] => image
            [orderby] => date
            [order] => DESC
            [posts_per_page] => 40
            [_acfuploader] => field_579b87ce88001
            [paged] => 1
        )
    )
```

So with *ajax_query_attachments_args*, it is then possible to modify the query :

```
add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', 'filter_product_attachments', 10, 1 );
function filter_product_attachments( $query = array() ) {
    if ($_POST['query']['_acfuploader'] == $THE_FIELD_ID){
        // Filter media query here
    }
    return $query;
}
```